# an alternative to (any) function

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a password validity code, but I didn't learn the (any) function yet so I should not use it
I'm looking for a different way to make the code work and check if there is lowercase, uppercase, and digits in the password. I thought about using a loop that checks each character, but I couldn't do it since I'm still learning loops

```
def main():
    P1 = str(input("Enter a password: "))
    if checkPassword(P1) == True:
        P2 = str(input("Confirm the Password: "))
        if P1 != P2:
            print("Password does not match!")
            main()
        else:
            print("The password is valid!")


def checkPassword(Pass):
    if len(Pass) < 8:
        print("Invalid Password: Should be at least 8 characters")
        return False
    if not any(char.isdigit() for char in Pass):
        print("Invalid Password: Should contain at least one digit")
        return False
    if not any(char.isupper() for char in Pass):
        print("Invalid Password: Should contain at least one uppercase character")
        return False
    if not any(char.islower() for char in Pass):
        print("Invalid Password: Should contain at least one lowercase character")
        return False
    return True

main()
```

Comment: Create a count variable for each of the three in the loop. Or you can use three boolean vars (e.g. uppercaseFound instead of uppercaseCount). Of course define these *outside* the loop and initialize to 0 or false. Happy coding.

Comment: What have you learned that can be used? are you restricted to loops?

Comment: @Sayse Its fine to use loops, it just that I'm a little bad with it and I get lost easily

Comment: What about list comprehension? Regex?

Comment: lambda expressions?

Comment: Nope I can't use comprehension, regex, or lambda expressions

Comment: _" just that I'm a little bad with it and I get lost easily"_ and we can help you if you show us what you tried. It's more helpful to know where you went wrong so you don't do it that way in the future, don't you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just make your own any function and then use that if you'd prefer,

```
def my_any(iterable, predicate):
    for item in iterable:
        if predicate(item):
              return True
    return False


if not my_any(Pass, lambda char: char.isdigit()):
    print("Invalid Password: Should contain at least one digit")
    return False
```

---

without a lambda, you need to figure out what errors have been triggered. and then use your if statement after that

```
digit_found = False
lower_found = False
upper_found = False
for char in Pass:
     if char.isdigit():
          digit_found = True
     elif char.isupper():
          upper_found = True

if not digit_found:
    print("Invalid Password: Should contain at least one digit")
    return False
```

Comment: This is a terrible idea; if using built-in `any` is not legitimate, making this work-around is ten times worse. I would far rather go to bat for someone using the publicly-documented built-ins than support a contrived version to dodge a constraint.

Comment: @Joffan - I'd never use the first approach but then I'm not being taught about what a for loop is currently, the second approach will potentially have some valid uses since i'm not iterating over the same list N times.

Comment: Just remove the pseudo-any section and it's a decent answer.

Comment: @Joffan - No because I'm not just answering to suit the current OP. it serves as an example of a further breakdown of what `any` does.

Comment: @Joffan OP says they're learning loops, so it's fair to presume that "you can't use `any()`" is an artificial constraint imposed by OP's instructor so that they actually learn what the instructor is trying to teach. A homemade `any()` is perfectly acceptable in this case, since it does what the builtin does.

Comment: It is definitely not acceptable; it is completely outside the correct learning level.

Comment: @Joffan - Thats fine to think that and you're entitled to your vote regardless

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is more than sufficient... but I wrote this so here it is anyways as another reference :')

This will print ALL applicable error messages.

```
def main():
    P1 = str(input("Enter a password: "))
    if checkPassword(P1) == True:
        P2 = str(input("Confirm the Password: "))
        if P1 != P2:
            print("Password does not match!")
            main()
        else:
            print("The password is valid!")

def check_values(P):
    digit_found, upper_found, lower_found = False, False, False
    for letter in P:
        if letter.isdigit():
            digit_found = True
        elif letter.isupper():
            upper_found = True
        elif letter.islower():
            lower_found = True
    return digit_found, upper_found, lower_found

def checkPassword(Pass):
    valid_pass = True
    if len(Pass) < 8:
        print("Invalid Password: Should be at least 8 characters")
        valid_pass = False
    digit, upper, lower = check_values(Pass)
    if not digit:
        print("Invalid Password: Should contain at least one digit")
        valid_pass = False
    if not upper:
        print("Invalid Password: Should contain at least one uppercase character")
        valid_pass = False
    if not lower:
        print("Invalid Password: Should contain at least one lowercase character")
        valid_pass = False
    return valid_pass

main()
```